# how to add 30 days in current date using php sql

Tags: php, mysql, date

using php how do you add 30 days in current date?... i have this sql code

```
start_subscription DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
end_subscription DATE,
```

I'm not sure about the data type of end_subscription.

Comment: How and when do you want the 30 days added?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE()) AS end_subscription
```

The first param for the item type (year/month/day), 1 for the amount of months

Comment: *Year for the item*?